# Where is file config in the past ~/.ssh?

Tags: git, ssh, windows-xp, config

I need config the Git to use SSH but I cant't find the config file in past ~/.ssh. 
How could I create this file?

Comment: What does this mean: "the past ~/.ssh" ?

Comment: think 'past' should be 'path'

Answer (score 2):

Follow a tutorial like this:
http://mrsimonelliott.com/blog/setting-git-and-github-windows-xp

I suspect you are not using GIT bash, as `~/` is not a normal windows pathing and you are probably trying to do this from a command prompt. `~/` means the current users home directory on POSIX systems.